# Twitter Bootstrap Horizontal Form to Vertical Form on different viewports

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[image: Horizontal Form]

form above looks great on desktop version but on Tablet and Mobile, marketing needs these labels (Name, SKU & ID) to be on TOP and Text Boxes (Name, SKU & ID) to be on BOTTOM. Does bootstrap provides any classes or tweaking to do that? Any help is appreciated guys. Thx.

Following is my Bootstrap CSS,

```
<div class="text-left">    
<div class="span12"> 
<div>
<h3 id="header">List of All Active Products</h3>
</div>       
<div class="row-fluid control-group form-inline">
<div class="span3">
<label for="ProductName">Name:</label>
<div class="input-append">
<input type="text" class="input-small search-query" placeholder="Name..."
id="ProductName" /><a href="#"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search icon- 
white"></i></span></a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="span3">
<label for="ProductSKU">SKU:</label>
<div class="input-append">
<input type="text" class="input-small search-query" placeholder="Product SKU..."
id="ProductSKU" /><a href="#"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search icon-white"></i></span></a>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="span3">
 <label for="ProductID">ID:</label>
 <div class="input-append">
 <input type="text" class="input-small search-query" placeholder="ID..."
 id="ProductID" /><a href="#"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search icon-
 white"></i></span></a>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="span3 text-right">
 <a href="/Products/AddProduct">+ Product</a>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but you may find it helpful: Most user experience testing data seems to support the fact that horizontal forms are generally harder for users to use to begin with. So, if you need vertical forms for a mobile platform, I would strongly consider just using vertical forms no matter the viewport size/type.

(That's not to say that every  field needs to be on its own line, e.g. First/Last name fields, but that, for the majority of inputs, they should flow from top to bottom, with field labels on top of field inputs.)